# Self signed certificate in keystore not working

Tags: java, jenkins, keystore, cacerts, jenkins-github-plugin

I am runnig a Gitlab and a Jenkins server as Docker Containers. I am trying to add my Gitlab server to my Jenkins server using the [Gitlab Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/). I've created a self signed certificate for Gitlab and added it to the java keystore in Jenkins with this command:

```
/opt/java/openjdk/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /opt/java/openjdk/bin/cacerts -alias gitlab -storepass changeit -noprompt -file /tmp/gitlab/gitlab.pem
```

Then I restarted the server. Nonetheless, I still get an error when I try to connect.

```
Failed to validate the account javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:259)
Caused: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:609)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:608)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:295)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiClient.get(GitLabApiClient.java:399)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiClient.get(GitLabApiClient.java:387)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.AbstractApi.get(AbstractApi.java:213)
Caused: org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.gitlab4j.api.AbstractApi.handle(AbstractApi.java:655)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.AbstractApi.get(AbstractApi.java:215)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.UserApi.getCurrentUser(UserApi.java:670)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabserverconfig.servers.GitLabServer$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(GitLabServer.java:433)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:398)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:410)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:78)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:141)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.plugins.locale.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:42)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: If your JDK (or JRE) is indeed in /opt/java/openjdk, then the default truststore is NOT in .../bin/cacerts; it is _probably_ accessed as .../lib/security/cacerts (possibly jssecacerts) but that may not be the actual file, it may be a symlink to somewhere else, depending on how your JDK was built. Find the file and check it is correct, _then_ add the new cert to it.

Comment: I've looked into /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security and there really is a cacerts folder. Then I checked if the /opt/java/openjdk/bin/cacerts is still there and I couldn't find it. So now I'm going to try adding the certificate to /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts as recommended by you @dave_thompson_085.

Comment: After adding the certificate to the keystore it did infact work. Altough I still got this error in my python code `Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore`   `Certificate was added to keystore` .